# How to detect `Keccak256` collision inputs

Tags: keccak, hash-algorithm

I'm trying to solve this -simple- small CTF challenge, the goal is to change the `solver` value to our address by calling the `talk` function:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Rivals {
    event Voice(uint256 indexed severity);

    bytes32 private encryptedFlag;
    bytes32 private hashedFlag;
    address public solver;

    constructor(bytes32 _encrypted, bytes32 _hashed) {
        encryptedFlag = _encrypted;
        hashedFlag = _hashed;
    }

    function talk(bytes32 _key) external {
        bytes32 _flag = _key ^ encryptedFlag;
        if (keccak256(abi.encode(_flag)) == hashedFlag) {
            solver = msg.sender;
            emit Voice(5);
        } else {
            emit Voice(block.timestamp % 5);
        }
    }
}
```

The whole idea of the challenge is to predict the `_key` value needs to be passed to `talk` function that **when it's passed to the keccak256 it will produce the `hasedFlag`**, the keccak256 is a hash algorithm, and so it is one way, how can we predict the input? Or are we talking here about possible hash collision? I did some research and I found that keccak256 is collision-safe for now.

PS: we can easily get the values of `ecryptedFlag` and `hashedFlag` by querying the storage.

Comment: There's something missing, reversing keccak256 isn't feasible. Either it is a well known value like empty string, or there's an alternative way to calculate it.

Comment: I also got confused too. I've provided everything provided by the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the values needed to re-validate js.
_key will have to be picked up by brute force.

Maybe this code will help

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const encryptedFlag = 'your_flag_value';  //bytes32
const hashedFlag = '0xYourHashedFlag';

let key = 1;
while(true) {
  const _key = ethers.encodeBytes32String(key.toString());
  const flagXOR = _key ^ encryptedFlag;
  const encodedFlag = ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder().encode(['bytes32'], [flagXOR]);
  const flagHash = ethers.keccak256(encodedFlag);

  if (flagHash === hashedFlag) {
    console.log(`key: ${key}`);
    break;
  }
  key++;
}
```

Comment: There are up to 2^256 possibilities, I believe we can not brute force it unless the wanted value is on the first ranges.

Comment: Right, I know.
Are you trying CTF ))

Comment: Yes, I'm x) Your proposed solution worth a try, I can see no alternative.